# Unset `manufacturer_filter` block in Custom Layout Update

Tags: blocks, layout

For just one particular category, I need to remove the manufacturer filter from the category sidebar.

My code for doing so (in the `custom_layout_update` field of the category editor) is here:

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
  <action method="unsetChild"><alias>manufacturer_filter</alias></action>
</reference>
```

Simple stuff, and it properly removes that child block from the `layout` as I would anticipate.

However, functions inside `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` depend on every attribute in the `_filterable_attributes` property having an associated `Block`.

It appears that by editing `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View::canShowOptions` to check for a "truthy" `$filter`, no errors occur and everything works as it should.

Is this a situation where I should override the class in `local`, or is there a preferred option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would normally make this kind of client-specific override as follows:

1. Create a local client module for all catalog functionality overrides and enhancements - `app/code/local/Clientname/Catalog`
2. Rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` class as `Clientname_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` and make it extend the original class
3. Override only the `canShowOptions` method

However it's best to avoid rewrites where possible - in this case I would choose to hide the filter using CSS rather than mess with the core code.

Comment: I prefer to avoid rewrites whenever possible--it's more likely that the client will install a plugin that needs to rewrite the same block as I did than they are to upgrade Magento core (which would outdate my `local/Mage` extend)

Comment: mpw: if a plugin rewrites the same block, you'd need your extension to rewrite the block from the plugin and extend your class from there.

There may be another solution without rewrites. It includes listening to the event `core_collection_abstract_load_before`, checking for the collection class and the current category page called. This way you could manipulate which attributes `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::getFilterableAttributes()` gets returned in the first place.

May work but it depends on you whether it it's worth to observe every `core_collection_abstract_load_before` dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way to do this, use javascript since CSS would require you to change the templates to mark them and that may not be an option wised for just one instance, but a simple (I load jquery)

```
//NOTE testing for location would be done first IE: title equals something
if(jQuery('.page-title')=="CAT I DONT WANT Manufacturer FOR"
    jQuery('#narrow-by-list dt').filter(function( index ) {
        return jQuery(this ).text() == "Manufacturer";
    }).css( "display", "none" ).next('dd').css( "display", "none" );
}
```

I have tested this out and it does work.  It doesn't require you to add extra weight of more classes if size of the html is a concern and with proper loading it'll be nearly unnoticeable.  Really it'll depend on how your site is made that will determin the best course, but I'm always in favor of something that is super targeted to one page but can be loaded globally.  Sort of matches your original wish.

This is just another option to @jharrison.au 's solution.